# What is wrong with my code to use Camera Cordova?

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I have tried everything for hours. I am sure it is a bracket or a stupid thing I miss. I already asked a question related to this, but it didn't solve my problem.

I am just trying to take a picture and store it in a variable to use it later.

I simplified my code to the maximum. There is one page, which is the following:

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Titre de la page</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,height=device-height,initial-scale=1"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>

<div class="ui-btn" id="prendrephoto1"> Prendre photo equipe1</div>

<button id="prendrephoto2"> Prendre photo equipe2</button>

<div id="myImage"></div>

<a class="ui-btn" href="#page2">Jouer</a>

</body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
var photo1;
var photo2;

$("#prendrephoto2").bind("click"function(){
alert('je suis le bouton 2');

});

$("#prendrephoto1").bind("click",function(){
alert("it is starting");
navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, 
{ quality: 50, 
  destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
  sourceType:Camera.PictureSourceType.Camera, }); 

});

function onSuccess(imageURI) {
     alert("It is working");
     //var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
    //image.src = imageURI;
}

function onFail(message) {
    alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}

//derniere balise jquery
});
</script>

</html>
```

Just to be sure I have done every thing right, following 2 screenshots of the xml and plugin.

[image]

[image]

Then, in the terminal:

```
cordova run --device
```

It is launching properly on my mIphone, but nothing happen when click the button.
Any help please?

A side-question, what would be the "developper javascript console" when app is running on Iphone ?

Comment: You can use the [safari dev tools](https://developer.apple.com/library/iad/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/GettingStarted/GettingStarted.html) to inspect the browser on your iPhone.

Comment: [GapDebug](https://www.genuitec.com/products/gapdebug/) might also be worth a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before deviceready, you CAN NOT use navigator.camera function.

You should write like this:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail,
            {
                quality: 50,
                destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
                sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.Camera,
            });

}
```

Comment: It is in the doc already but in jquery: $(document).ready(function()

Comment: @Sulot I konw, what you use is **dom** ready. We should use cordova plugin function after **deviceready**. [cordova-plugin-camera](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera), you can read the third paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

Seems everything is fine except one syntax error at line no:37

add "," in line 37 after click...

```
$("#prendrephoto2").bind("click", function(){
       alert('je suis le bouton 2');
});
```

Comment: Yep, but the Camera is not launching...

Comment: remove " , " here   sourceType:Camera.PictureSourceType.Camera, at line no: 47

Answer (score 0):

Change this.

```
$("#prendrephoto2").bind("click"function(){
 alert('je suis le bouton 2');
});
```

To this.

```
$("#prendrephoto2").bind("click",function(){
 alert('je suis le bouton 2');
 alert('Click Working');
});
```

It's look like you missing comma so it's gives you syntax error.

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Hum at least it is trigger "alert", but it is not launching the camera.

Comment: so you need to capture image with camera right ?

Comment: Yep! That my mere goal! :)

Comment: Basically, I want to take 2 picture, save them in photo1 and photo2, and use it later on a one page app.

Comment: I am just trying to turn the code in all possibilities, it is not working and I just don't understand why... It is driving me crazy. It has been 3 days, that I am just trying and trying different possibilities, copy-pasting template. And nothing works.

Comment: have you installed the camera plugin with full git link ?